# I am trying to figure out how to use the google drive api along with python to update file permissions as well as ownership

Tags: python-3.x

I took the code from [the Google Drive API page for managing shares](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#transferring_ownership) and did some modifications to it to be able to transfer the ownership of a specific file but I keep getting back the following error

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

file_id = 'XXXXXX'
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception:
        # Handle error
        print(exception)
    else:
        print("Permission Id: %s" % response.get('id'))

batch = drive_service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
user_permission = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer',
    'emailAddress': 'XXX@gmail.com'
}
batch.add(drive_service.permissions().create(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=user_permission,
        fields='id',
))
domain_permission = {
    'type': 'domain',
    'role': 'reader',
    'domain': 'example.com'
}
batch.add(drive_service.permissions().create(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=domain_permission,
        fields='id',
))
batch.execute()
```

The error I get is that

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1w43iXVO04QhDl-eWHi75ImSdxu-_V5xp/permissions?fields=id&alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1w43iXVO04QhDl-eWHi75ImSdxu-_V5xp/permissions?fields=id&alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

But i am not sure if its an issue with the code itself or with how I setup the credentials for the API. does someone have experience with the Google Drive API for Python and can give me a pointer on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be obvious but your credentials don't have authorisation.

Have you made sure your loading the correct credentials.json and scope?
You can get the same error using the quickstart credentials for different api products.

try commenting out this out when you try to load the correct credentials and scope.

```
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
```

Comment: it was long these lines. what the issue is that, I had previously authenticated with a different scope and then when I changed that scope, the script was using the `token.pickle` that was generated with the previous scope which has less authority. I had to remove the `token.pickle` file and it finally started working after some other tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Modify scopes:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata']
```

Delete the generated token.pickle file.
Then rerun the code.
Specific permissions can be viewed here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create?authuser=3#auth

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and elaborate a little why this is solution of problem and eventually point to relevant documentation? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, the document address has been increased.